# Npm isn't getting automatically installed on installing node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

While hosting my webapp on heroku I got a message of some bugs in my npm package, my npm package was of version 3 and node.js was of version 8, I wrote thinking that I can update my npm version I tried to update it but the version remained same so I decided to uninstall it and wrote the command "npm uninstall " and than again tried to install npm but in vain ,finally I uninstalled my node.js and reinstalled tha npm will automatically get installed with it, but this too didn't work now I have node of version 10 with no npm which I got to know by checking version of npm which gave me message of "command not found ", now my every try to install npm has failed , may anyone suggest me what I can do to restore my losses and resume my work.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install npm`?

Comment: On which operating system are you trying this operation?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have Linux or Windows. First I would check if the npm folder is in path.
You can follow one of these two to add to path if it is not done yet.

- [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10)
- [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20733132/5923584)

Alternatively you can install node with node version manager (nvm):

- [nvm linux and mac](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
- [nvm windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)